# map Html.BeginForm to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hello
my question is an exact replica of [ASP.NET MVC Routing , Html.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918014/asp-net-mvc-routing-html-beginform)  ,
im posting again because the suggested solution doesnt work..
my View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home",FormMethod.Get))
{
        input name="q" id="q" type="text" class="ipt" />
        @Html.DropDownList("SearchType", new SelectList(
      new[] { "All Words", "Any Word", "ZipCode" }, ("All Words")))


        input type="image" src="../../Content/images/search.png" />
}
```

(i've removed < character so it shows in the question)
the generated url is this http://localhost:4893/Home/Search?q=Brabant&SearchType=ZipCode&x=51&y=5, i want it to be **Home/Search/Brabant/ZipCode**

---

**EDIT :**

i dont think it has something to do with routes, the javascript doesnt work! my problem is generating the url in first place, not matching it.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
        var data = $('input[name="q"]', this).val();
        window.location.href = this.action + '/' + encodeURIComponent(data);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I believe we'd need to see the code for the route (in global.asax) to help.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
null, // Route name
"", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
);
routes.MapRoute(null,
  "Home/Search/{q}/{SearchType}/{x}/{y}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" }, // Defaults
  new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
);
            routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{q}/{SearchType}/Page{page}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" }, // Defaults
        new { page = @"\d+" } // Constraints: page must be numerical
    );
            routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript has to be **inside** the form

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('form').submit(function () {
                        var q = $('input[name="q"]', this).val();
                        var e = document.getElementById("SearchType");
                        var SearchType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

                        var idx = window.location.href.indexOf("/", 7);
                        var siteName = window.location.href.substring(0, idx).replace("http://", "");
                        var newPath = "http://" + siteName + '/' + q + '/' + SearchType;
                        window.location.href = newPath;
                        return false;
                    });
                </script>
                <div class="pf sleft">
                    <input name="q" id="q" type="text" class="ipt" />
                    @Html.DropDownList("SearchType", new SelectList(
              new[] { "All Words", "Any Word", "ZipCode" }, ("All Words")))
                </div>
                <div class="pf sright">
                    <input type="image" onclick="return CheckInput();" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/search.png")" />
                </div>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

specify a new route in Global.ascx

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              "SearchRoute",
              "{controller}/{action}/{q}/{SearchType}/{x}/{y}",
              new {controller = "Home",action = "Search",q="",SearchType=""},

            );
```

---

EDIT:

after the routes you have posted, your routes looks fine, try defining them above the default route

Answer (score 0):

do you get any javascript errors? have you checked in firebug or chrome dev tools?

why dont you just submit the form

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home",FormMethod.Get))
{
        input name="q" id="q" type="text" class="ipt" />
        @Html.DropDownList("SearchType", new SelectList(
      new[] { "All Words", "Any Word", "ZipCode" }, ("All Words")))


        <input id="submit" type="image" src="../../Content/images/search.png" />
     ...^ you had a type here i guess
}
```

and the jquery

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
 $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```